# Google play store not recognizing new package name of app

Tags: java, android, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I'm trying to publish an app into playstore.

Previously the package name was bk.myapp. Now I've refactored it into some other thing from the manifest file itself.

Now bk.myapp is replaced with new package name everywhere. There is not even a single occurrence left for bk.myapp.

Now I've generated a new apk file using new keystore etc.

Now I've uploaded this apk into play console. It is showing the package name as bk.myapp which is illogical. Can some one help me with what's going on actually?

**EDIT:** Manifest file added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="bharat.sos_tarp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service android:name="bharat.sos_tarp.FirebaseListeneingService"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value=""/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity android:name="bharat.sos_tarp.Login">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="bharat.sos_tarp.MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="bharat.sos_tarp.NotificationReceiver">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="bharat.sos_tarp.MapActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="bharat.sos_tarp.AlertSuccessActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="bharat.sos_tarp.showContactsRecview.ViewContacts">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="bharat.sos_tarp.addContactsRecview.AddContacts">
        </activity>

        <service android:name="bharat.sos_tarp.LockService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: the package name is set in the `build.gradle` file

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Thanks man will this solve my problem?

Comment: It's showing some error when I try to build with new package name

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'new_name_here'

Comment: that's because your google services config is generated for old package. You will have to register new project, and re-generate the config file

Comment: can you show your manifest file and your build.gradle file ?

Comment: ok wait I'll update the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you have set the applicationId correctly in your build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "new_package_name"
        ...
    }
```